# Keep a look-out for passing dates, then take action "real-time"

Tags: sql-server

Let's say I have a table with a date column; can I attach some sort of "watcher" that can take action if the date gets smaller than getdate()? Note that the date is larger than getdate() at the time of insertion.

Are there any tools that I might be unaware of in SQL Server 2008/2012?

Or would the best option be to poll the data from another application?

Edit: Note that there is no insertion/update taking place.

Comment: Add a constraint on date column to check if date being inserted is larger than getdate().

Comment: @Skalis, I have no experience with this, but you could think of extendet events (http://www.sqlteam.com/article/introduction-to-sql-server-2008-extended-events). Another idea was a flag-column to be set within an UPDATE TRIGGER. This to query is easy ...

Comment: @Shnugo Thank you, but there is no insertion/update.

Comment: Well since you always know exactly what time this is going to happen then you have an advantage in that it can be scheduled rather than having to continually poll. Without more info it's still hard to know if a SQL Job is appropriate though.

Comment: @shawnt00 Problem is that I _don't_ know at what time the date column gets passed by todays date&time.

Comment: Skalis, but if there is not insertion or update you know everything **before** it happens. I think this is what @shawnt00 meant with "advantage". So: you don't have to react "realtime" but you can execute something in a scheduled plan.

Comment: @Shnugo Bad phrasing on my part. What I meant was that updates/inserts never qualify for the check at the time of the action. But the rows need to be continually checked after they have been updated/inserted.

Comment: @Shnugo Triggers or a stored procedure would allow you to discover this information and adjust the schedule accordingly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could set up a **SQL Job** which runs periodically and executes a stored procedure which can then handle the logic around past dates.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/ms187910.aspx

For example a SQL Job could be set up to run once daily to find out user's birthdays and send out an automated email.

In your case a job could be set up every minute (if required) which detects past dates and does something with those records. I would suggest adding some kind of flag to each record so that it isn't actioned the next time the job runs.

---

Alternatively if you have a lot of servers and databases, you could centralise your job scheduling using a third-party tool such as [ActiveBatch](http://www.advsyscon.com/home/products/activebatch/job-scheduling.aspx).

Comment: Thank you, but this seems awfully close to the polling solution I briefly discussed in the question.

Comment: @Skalis if you want to periodically check date values, then whatever the solution is it'll be a form of polling. A SQL agent job seems like a good fit for your problem. What's your issue with this type of solution? This isn't polling from another application, SQL Jobs are part of SQL Server, designed to perform tasks on a scheduled basis.

Comment: @Tanner That was basically my question; do I need to poll? You answered my question, thank you. The issue is more about if there are any built-in tools for continually checking a "constraint", which there does not seem to be.